# How can I re-run my init.lua?

Tags: neovim, init

If I'm making changes in my `init.lua` file, is there anyway to have those changes reflect in my current copy of Neovim without restarting the editor?

Not limited to mappings, but is there something that can clear out the settings and like re `source` them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I found, and I'm not sure it's the best method is with

```
:luafile ~/.config/nvim/init.lua
```

That seems to reinitialize the mappings.