# init.lua does not run, silent failure

Tags: neovim, linux-debian, init.lua

Trying to set up a new VM, I copied over my dotfiles and they weren't working. I've reduced my `init.lua` to something very simple. All it has is,

```
vim.opt.tabstop = 2
```

Yet, when I start up vim, nothing happens. Tabstop isn't set. I get no error nor warning. Moreover, if I try to set it with

```
:luado("vim.opt.tabstop = 2")
```

I get,

> E5109: Error while creating lua chunk: [string ""]:1: syntax err
> or near 'end'

And if I try to [run `init.lua` again](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37224/5078),

> E5112: Error while creating lua chunk: /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:1: unexpected
> symbol near `'<ef>'`

Any idea on what the problem is here, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

## Requires Neovim 0.5 or newer

I was trying to run `init.lua` on the [Neovim in Debian Bullseye, which at this time is v0.4.4](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/neovim). The [Neovim in Debian Bookworm is 0.7.2](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/neovim). I didn't realize this VM I set up was on Buster and not Bookworm.

[The patch to add support for `init.lua` went in Dec 1, 2020](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/767cd8b17b71f78bdd4c2e0dd8d3f4f0f1551381), while [Debian Buster had the soft-freeze at 2019-02-12](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster)